# How to run particular transition in MotionLayout?

Tags: android, animation, android-constraintlayout, androidx, android-motionlayout

I have a MotionScene with 4 ConstraintSets representing 4 states of screen (loading states) and with 3 Transitions between them.
When my app state changes from e.g. loading to processing, I want to run Transition 1 (set1 -> set2), when state changes again, I want to run Transition 2 (set2 -> set3). And I can't find a way to do it.

I tried next:

To set current transition with

```
     motion_layout.setTransition(R.id.set1, R.id.set2)
     motion_layout.transitionToState(R.id.set2)
```

---

To just set transition

```
motion_layout.setTransition(R.id.set1)
```

---

To transition to some state:

```
motion_layout.transitionToState(R.id.set1)
```

but all of the above methods run all my sets together, even if I use app:autoTransition="none" .

---

I tried to put everything in one Transition and set app:progress = 0 on , and then control state of animation with progress:

```
 motion_layout.setProgress(0.25f, 1.0f)
```

which just runs all animation to the end, or I tried

```
motion_layout.progress = 0.25f
```

which don't animate, it just shows me 0.25 progress of animation without any motion.

How to control the flow of animation? How to run particular set? Would it be better to use progress? How to solve it?

P.S.
I use

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta7'
```

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer - I haven't noticed the problem for the first time ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure what you are doing (not enough code) but here is a as simple as I can make it 5 state example.

```
<MotionScene 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/state1"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/state2"/>
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/state2"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/state3"/>

<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/state3"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/state4"/>

<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/state4"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/state5"/>

<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/state1"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/state5"/>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state1">
    <Constraint         android:id="@+id/view">
    <CustomAttribute motion:attributeName="text" motion:customStringValue="state1" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state2">
    <Constraint         android:id="@+id/view">
        <Transform android:translationX="-100dp"/>
        <CustomAttribute motion:attributeName="text" motion:customStringValue="state2" />
    </Constraint>

</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state3">
    <Constraint         android:id="@+id/view">
        <Transform android:translationX="100dp"/>
        <CustomAttribute motion:attributeName="text" motion:customStringValue="state3" />

    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state4">
    <Constraint         android:id="@+id/view">
        <Transform android:translationY="-100dp"/>
        <CustomAttribute motion:attributeName="text" motion:customStringValue="state4" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state5">
    <Constraint         android:id="@+id/view">
        <Transform android:translationY="100dp"/>
        <CustomAttribute motion:attributeName="text" motion:customStringValue="state5" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```

this scene file works with this main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
android:id="@+id/motionlayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#4DD3D3"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="transition"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:onClick="nextState"
    />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

and this MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.multistate

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun nextState(view: View) {
   when (motionlayout.currentState ) {
       R.id.state1 -> motionlayout.transitionToState(R.id.state2)
       R.id.state2 -> motionlayout.transitionToState(R.id.state3)
       R.id.state3 -> motionlayout.transitionToState(R.id.state4)
       R.id.state4 -> motionlayout.transitionToState(R.id.state5)
       R.id.state5 -> motionlayout.transitionToState(R.id.state1)
   }
}
}
```

Comment: I will test it and will be back with answer tomorrow

Comment: Works perfectly. Now I have to dig and understand why my layout is not working.

Comment: How does motionlayout determine which state (1-5) to be its initial state? ie. what should motionLayout.currentState return when run for the first time?

Comment: Due to historical reasons the start state of the first transition in the file is the initial state.
(original motionLayout had only 2 states and a transition)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have   it should only transition to the state you call if you call ml.transitionToState(R.id.xx);

Remove all autoTransition attributes in you motionScene

Comment: Not working. I set autoTransition=false on every ConstraintSet

Comment: @StayCool just add motion:autoTransition="none" to transactions in layout description.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this:

```kotlin
motion_layout.setTransitionListener(
    object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
        override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Float) {
        }

        override fun onTransitionCompleted(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, currentId: Int) {
            when(currentId) {
                R.id.set1 -> motion_layout.setTransition(currentId, R.id.set2)
                R.id.set2 -> motion_layout.setTransition(currentId, R.id.set3)
                R.id.set3 -> motion_layout.setTransition(currentId, R.id.set4)
                R.id.set4 -> motion_layout.setTransition(currentId, R.id.set1)
        }
    }
)

motion_layout.transitionToEnd()
```

And control then call motion_layout.transitionToEnd() every time you want to change the state

Comment: Actually I just want to stop Transition after one is completed. And trigger next one after some time. I will try this callback and be right back with feedback

Comment: As I said, it will stop at R.id.set2, and after some time just invoke `motion_layout.transitionToEnd` and it will go to R.id.set3

Comment: This motionLayout is so messy. Actually, I couldn't even try your solution. Because my scene was completely broken, and I wasn't able to just run it all to the end. Will be back with this task in few days, and I will try your solution first